# laravel 5 : showing posted data when a validation request failed on an update form

Tags: request, laravel-5

I've a question : when a validation request FAILED on an UPDATE form, how can I show the posted data, on which errors occurs ?

In this exemple, it justs shows the data fetched from the DB (not the "old", previouly modified) :

```
// ****************
// Controller
// ****************
public function update(Article $article)
{   
        return view('article.update',compact('article'));
}

public function handleupdate(Requests\UpdateArticleRequest $request)
 {
    $article = Article::findOrFail(Request::input('id'));
    $article->fill($request->all());
    $article->save();
    return Redirect::to('/');
 }

// ****************
// ValidationRequest
// ****************

class UpdatearticleRequest extends Request {

public function authorize()
{
       return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
      'name'    => 'required | min:3',
      'description' => 'required | max:255
        ];
}
```

}

I've seen the Request::old and Request::flash() but I don't understant how to "glue" all these things together.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Paguemaou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Laravel Form (eg Form::text, Form::select) then these will be filled automatically from the value in the session.

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-forms for more info as Form-s are not installed by default in Laravel 5 anymore.

Comment: I currently use plain html fields. I'll try with Form fields. Many thanks for your answer.